# How to submit a form using a javascript function in JSF w/ Richfaces, w/o the form name or id?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

How would I go about submitting a form in Richfaces *without* the form name or id from javascript? I was thinking I might be able to use the jsFunction tag, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

*As a note, I can set the name of the function in jsFunction*

**EDIT** RF 3.3, JSF 1.2

Comment: RichFaces 3.3.x or 4.x? JSF 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible without repeating the form ID and without knowing the exact location of the form in the HTML DOM tree as opposed to the element from where you'd like to submit the form.

You could at best use the EL function `rich:element()`. Imagine that you've a form like this:

```
<h:form id="myform">
```

then you could use `rich:element()` as follows in JS context (in a JSF page!) to get the form as HTML DOM element:

```
<script>
    var form = #{rich:element('myform')};
    form.submit();
</script>
```

This get namely generated to the HTML as follows

```
<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('myformOrWhateverClientIdItHas');
    form.submit();
</script>
```

#### See also:

- [RichFaces built-in client functions](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/12/richfaces-built-in-client-functions/)

---

**Update**: Or, when the JS function is invoked by an element inside the form itself, then just use `this.form` to get the parent form element of the HTML DOM element in question. E.g.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox onclick="doSomething(this.form)" />
```

with

```
function doSomething(form) {
    // ...
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible if I could know the id of an element inside the form? Perhaps a hidden button or jsFunction or something? Also, as always, your help is greatly appreciated BalusC.

Comment: That depends totally on the JS context. Where and how exactly are you executing the JS function? See updated answer for an example.

Comment: The javascript is external to the form, but I think I could combine the two parts of your answer to `#{rich:element('myHiddenElementInAForm').form.submit()`. I'll report back if it works.

Comment: This solution allowed me to submit my form externally by knowing the id of an element in the form! Thanks BalusC!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the form name or id to submit using a4j:jsFunction.

Comment: Right, but how do I have a4j:jsFunction submit the entire enclosing form and not just the `value`? In other words, how do I use a4j:jsFunction to trigger a full form submit?

Comment: It always submits the entire form.

Comment: Hmm, that wasn't my experience, but it was what I expected would happen. Maybe there was something else breaking the life cycle. Thanks for the answer, I'll look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a4j:jsFunction, don't forget to add execute="@form" in order to submit all form