# issue with htmlDatatable in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have one `dataTable` in my screen. In the column header there is a `selectBooleanCheckBox`. If I
select it then all the boolean check boxes are get selected and deselected if I deselect the header boolean check box. My datatable is binded is with htmlDatatable. In bean all values are being set but it is not reflected in UI. Kindly help....

```
<t:dataTable id="physicalAccessDetailsDataTable1" binding="#{bean.htmlDataTable}">
   <f:facet name="header">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectAll" value="#{bean.editablePhysical}"
                                 valueChangeListener="#{bean.selectAllFromPhysicalDatatable}" 
                                 onclick="submit()" />
   </f:facet>
```

here is my bean code...

```
public String selectAllFromPhysicalDatatable(ValueChangeEvent vcep) {
    if (editablePhysical == false) {
        System.out.println(editablePhysical);
        editablePhysical = true;

        for (PhysicalAccessDetail physicalAccessDetail : physicalAccessDetailsList) {
            System.out.println("INside loop of true");
            physicalAccessDetail.setEditable(true);
            }
        } else {
            editablePhysical = false;

            for (PhysicalAccessDetail physicalAccessDetail : physicalAccessDetailsList) {
                physicalAccessDetail.setEditable(false);
            }
        }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what scope does your managed bean has ?

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi my bean is in session scope.

Comment: what about the `submit()` method

Comment: please check BalusC answer here, I think you should use similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102577/how-to-submit-a-form-using-a-javascript-function-in-jsf-w-richfaces-w-o-the-fo